# Session not passing right value through files

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I am going crazy and need some tips and help. Working with custom cms and php programming language. I am working on online site on server.

Problem is next:

Session start is ok, In **functions.php** I start `session['lng']` and put _LNG constant in it and it's ok, passing alright.

When I call `session['lng']` in my other files I always get the same language constant (en) but I am passing (hr) or (de)?? I checked 10 time if session is set somewhere else but it isn't.

How can I check where's the problem...I really don't know what to do next

Comment: Share code please but you need to start you pages with <?php session_ start(); ?>. Should be the very first thing. You can also unset session if problem persists and clear cache. Then retry to see if session data is passed correctly

Comment: By saying i start session['lng'] , what's you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Did you place this at the start of other files before accessing session variables. It's required to access session vars.

```
<?php
session_start();
```

Comment: are you sure that this is the problem?

Comment: This is just a suggestion. Please don't post answer until and unless it is required/helpful for user. Rather than, use comment section for all your suggestions. **In Stack Overflow, Suggestions Are Always Welcome.**

Comment: Yes @RafaelShkembi . If you are not doing it then this is the problem for sure. If everything else you are doing is fine.

Comment: @NanaPartykar It's the answer to his question not a suggestion

Comment: in every file you should start session and then check for session variable